# Trying to have 2 drop down comboboxes that have the same function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

How can I have 2 drop down combo boxes on the same page?

here is what I have now:

```
<div class="ui-widget" >
<p>  <label>test: </label></p>
  <select id="combobox">
    <option value="">Select one...</option>
    <option value="first">first</option>
    <option value=">second">second</option>

  </select>
  <button style = "margin-left:35px;"type="button" onclick="f1()">Go!</button>

</div>
...
<div class="ui-widget">
<select id="combobox">
    <option value="">Select one...</option>
    <option value="test">test</option>
    <option value="test2">test2</option>


  </select>
</div>
```

I am pretty sure I am not able to have 2 of the same id's like I do. Right now the first one works but the second doesnt. How can I fix this?

Im using this dropdown http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox

Comment: where is your jQuery?

Comment: You have the same id twice.

Comment: 2 of the same IDs is definitely the problem. What are you trying to accomplish, exactly?

Comment: you can use class instead of id and apply combo box to class instead of id like $( ".combobox" ).combobox();

Comment: @Bhadra I think that is what Im looking for, I will give it a shot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the same ID for 2 different elements is not valid.

If you're calling `.combobox()` on the two, simply use classes instead:

```
<select id="combobox1" class="combo"></select>
<select id="combobox2" class="combo"></select>
```

And then do `$('.combo').combobox();`.